# How to ask "how can I buy this?"

Tags: translation

There's a JP musician whose work I really love. He sells his songs for $2 apiece online. This is all well and good.

But a while ago, he uploaded an alternate version of one of his songs, and I've found I like it way more than the original. Problem is, he never put it up for sale (and also the quality is low.) So, I want to send him a message on Twitter and ask him if there's any way I can buy it in high quality.

The only thing I can think of is asking him if 買い方がありますか, but that really doesn't sound right at all.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you intended to type 買い方がありますか, which sounds awkward but still understandable.

The way I would say it, if on Twitter, would be something along the lines of

この曲{きょく}を購入{こうにゅう}することはできますか？

This translates to "Can (I) buy this song?"

You can alternatively say

この曲{きょく｝を買｛か｝うことはできますか？

which is the same thing but a little more informal in my opinion.

Comment: Oh, you're right, that was a typo! I changed my original post to read 買い方.

Comment: The OP is not asking for '*Can I* buy this?' They simply made a sentence meaning that because they can't think of how to ask that. They want '*How* can I buy this?' どうしたら買えるんですか, I think.

Comment: @AeonAkechi I understood _"[is there] any way I can buy this"_ as _"is it possible to buy this"_ , but your way also makes sense.